# drop characters from end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, I need to drop the last two characters from a series of item numbers in our database. not all the numbers are the same format and i only need to drop characters from certain ones. the numbers i need to truncate look like this DOR-12345_X where _X is a revision letter. i tried this

```
 SELECT LEFT(IV00103.VNDITNUM,(LEN(IV00103.VNDITNUM)-2) 
 FROM IV00103 
 WHERE LEFT STR = 'DOR'
```

but it doesn't like the syntax near `FROM` or the `STR = 'DOR'`

Can anyone assist? Do you need more info? I'm really a newb at SQL =) THANKS!

-jon

Comment: Also, the `LEFT` in the `WHERE` should be `LEFT(STR,3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't like the syntax near `FROM` because you're missing a closing bracket on the `LEFT`. I suspect what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IV00103.VNDITNUM LIKE 'DOR%' THEN LEFT(IV00103.VNDITNUM,(LEN(IV00103.VNDITNUM)-2)) ELSE IV00103.VNDITNUM END AS VNDITNUM
FROM IV00103
```

That selects absolutely everything from the IV00103 table, removing those last two characters only from those that have a value in the `VNDITNUM` column beginning with `DOR`.

EDIT: If you want to actually update the contents of the table, you could do it this way using a WHERE:

```
UPDATE IV00103
SET VNDITNUM = LEFT(IV00103.VNDITNUM,(LEN(IV00103.VNDITNUM)-2))
WHERE VNDITNUM LIKE 'DOR%'
```

If you only need the ones that match the pattern `DOR-somecharacters_asinglecharacter` then you should probably do:

```
UPDATE IV00103
SET VNDITNUM = LEFT(IV00103.VNDITNUM,(LEN(IV00103.VNDITNUM)-2))
WHERE VNDITNUM LIKE 'DOR-%\__' ESCAPE '\'
```

The `\_` is an escaped underscore, which will be treated as an *actual* underscore. The `ESCAPE '\'` part tells SQL that the `\` character is being used to escape special characters in the pattern. The second `_` is the special character, and matches a single character.

Comment: @Dreamwalker Depends how you interpret the question, but based on what they said I don't think the WHERE clause was the correct method at all. It sounded to me like they want to select everything, but only remove the last two characters from the columns that have that particular format.

Comment: thank you! that got me the selection i wanted =) is there a way to update that field with the selection in the same query? or will i have to run a different one to update those fields? so sorry, im really new at SQL. its all in one column, but only want to truncate the DOR numbers. this seems to have done what i want. i just need to update the column with the truncated numbers

Comment: @Anthony Grist Yes you got a point there it's not like he is running an update

Comment: @Dreamwalker Well, after all that it seems he does actually want to do an UPDATE, so WHERE would be the better option.

Comment: @JonM Updated my answer with the relevant UPDATE syntax. I initially assumed you wanted to keep the contents in the database the same, but then not include the revision letter when querying for some application.

Comment: thank you guys. very much! they were going to have someone use an excel spreadsheet to change all these numbers and then have me import the data >< ouch.  and you were correct in your first answer since i didnt tell you i wanted to update. that was my bad!

Comment: ahh crumbs! there are DOR- numbers that dont have _X at the end that also got truncated. how do i make it only drop the _X characters, rather than dropping 2 characters from any DOR-number?

Comment: hmmm. guess i cant do that. i now fully understand why you dont use the underscore in SQL data. thanks again guys.

Comment: yep. thank you! i just figured out the syntax on my own! go me lol! thanks again! WHERE IV00103.VNDITNUM like 'DOR-_____[_]%'

Answer (score 4):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
 SELECT LEFT(IV00103.VNDITNUM, LEN(IV00103.VNDITNUM)-2) 
 FROM IV00103 
 WHERE LEFT(IV00103.VNDITNUM, 3) = 'DOR'
```

Or:

```
WHERE IV00103.VNDITNUM like 'DOR%'
```